# How to automatically connect to WiFi once ethernet stops working

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ethernet, automation

So my problem is fairly easy:

The wired ethernet connection stops working from time to time but stays connected.
What I want to do is keep the WiFi turned off, or at least disconnected, as long as the ethernet is working and provides an active connection to the internet.

Once the ethernet loses connection, so e.g. a timeout to DNS or something similar the WiFi-Adapter should be turned on/ connect to the network.
The ethernet cable stays connected, just no uplink.

are there any working solutions to this day?

*EDIT:*
The Wifi would connect to a different network.
The wired network is connected to a hardware-firewall, while the WiFi would connect to a private hotspot from a fritzbox.

Comment: The connection still works, just the outbound line doesn't. There's no way the interface can know this. You'd need a 'smart' solution that can see the outbound connection fails. This is usually the job of a clever router with failover. I've never seen it implemented at desktop level. [Though this just as a comment, in case anyone does know a workaround].

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
So basically I need a way to check if the uplink is still working on the wired connection. 
Is there a scripted way through powershell, or cmd or smth?

Comment: idk, sorry - just thought I'd drop in some background. 'Fraid I don't have a solution, sorry.

Comment: How do you define "stops working but stays connected"? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Ping will tell you if you are reaching the web.  Could run a scripted loop and take action after x failures within  y time. Probably makes more sense to get a dual Wan appliance or run pfsense in a vm or dedicated hw to manage that.